# Tensorflow does not work in PyCharm - DLL load failed: The specific module could not be found

Tags: python, tensorflow, pycharm

I've just installed a fresh version of Tensorflow on my machine and I've created a conda environment with tensorflow-gpu.

I ran the typical GPU utilization code in my command line, with my environment activated, to check if TF is using my GPU and it's fine.

```
import tensorflow as tf
with tf.device('/gpu:0'):
    a = tf.constant([1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0], shape=[2, 3], name='a')
    b = tf.constant([1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0], shape=[3, 2], name='b')
    c = tf.matmul(a, b)

with tf.Session() as sess:
    print (sess.run(c))
```

[image]

But when I try to set up PyCharm to use the interpreter for this environment, it just fails to. The Run configuration and Project configuration is the same, and they're supposed to use the `gpu_env` environment, but when running the same check code in PyCharm, it just fails with:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/AccesaProjects/TFProj/tf_code.py", line 1, in <module>
    import tensorflow as tf
  File "C:\Users\radu.gheorghiu\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\gpu_env\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\__init__.py", line 24, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow  # pylint: disable=unused-import
  File "C:\Users\radu.gheorghiu\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\gpu_env\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\__init__.py", line 47, in <module>
    import numpy as np
  File "C:\Users\radu.gheorghiu\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\gpu_env\lib\site-packages\numpy\__init__.py", line 140, in <module>
    from . import _distributor_init
  File "C:\Users\radu.gheorghiu\AppData\Local\Continuum\anaconda3\envs\gpu_env\lib\site-packages\numpy\_distributor_init.py", line 34, in <module>
    from . import _mklinit
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Project settings are:

[image]

And Run/Debug configuration settings are:

[image]

This used to work last time I tried it a few months ago and I'm not sure what's not working now.

Any hints would be really helpful! Thanks!

Comment: if it's pycharm's problem, than you can try to recache pycharm (file - invalidate cache/restrat)

Comment: I believe you are facing the known PyCharm issue https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-35141

Comment: @PavelKarateev yes, that was it. there's an answer that suggests starting pycharm from the terminal, once you're in the right conda environment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem seems to be version specific, in this case: **`2019.1`**. The solution is more of a work-around until this PyCharm bug is resolved.

As an alternative, you can do this:

- open the Anaconda terminal
- activate the appropriate environment
- start the PyCharm IDE from the terminal